# get_absolute_url in django-categories

Tags: python, django-models, categories

I would like to know this method must be to work up due to I've tried to implement but I could not.
Actually I've tried entering to the shell through

```
python manage.py shell
c=Category.objects.get(pk = 3)
c.get_absolute_url
#I got <bound method Category.get_absolute_url of <Category: Category2>>
c.get_absolute_url()
#It Doesn't work
```

I want to implement it within another model named Article that it's a foreign key to Category model

My intention is to have a method in Article like

```
def get_abs_url(self):
   c=Category.objects.get(pk=self.category)
   return c.get_absolute_url() + '/' + self.slug
```

Something like that

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could supply more information regarding your models and what you are trying to achieve. Something like this might help:

models.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='article')
    ...
```

Where ever you return a queryset in views:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ArticleView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['articles'] = Article.objects.all().select_related('category')
    return context
```

In templates:

```
{% for article in articles %}
    {% for category in article.category %}
        {{ category.get_absolute_url }}/{{ category.slug }} # this will return a string: abs_url/slug
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Read about select_related here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

You could also take a look at implementing Managers: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#django.db.models.Manager

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I overcame this problems throw the follow solution, first of all, my intention have always been to get something like that
/c/slug_category_parent/slug_first_children/.../last_children.
I've resolved throw this solution in settings.py:

```
cat_url= lambda c: cat_url(c.parent) + '/' +c.slug if c.parent else '/c/'+ c.sl
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES = {
    'categories.category': lambda c: cat_url(c),
}
```